# Get Userfrosting / Slim to work with Controller Class

Tags: php, slim, psr-4, userfrosting

I'm completly new to the MVC pattern and I find it really hard to understand without programming, so I set up the Userfrosting Framework which is based on Slim. I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.userfrosting.com/) and I could see the default starting page, log in, etc.

Now I added a sprinkle called site, like in the tutorial and created a src directory in the sprinkle. But when I add a Controller class and a routing file, things get bad:

```
Callable UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Site\Controller\MainController does not exist
```

site/routes/mainRoutes.php:

```
<?php
$app->get('/', 'UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Site\Controller\MainController:getWelcome');
```

site/src/Controller/MainController.php:

```
<?php
namespace UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Site\Controller;
use UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Core\Controller\SimpleController;

class MainController extends SimpleController
{
    public function getWelcome($request, $response, $args)
    {

        return $response->write("Welcome to life");

    }
}
```

site/composer.json:

```
{ 
   ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "UserFrosting\\Sprinkle\\Site\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I even start to find the problem? It's a really overwhelming topic.

Comment: Did you run `composer update` after creating your Sprinkle?

Comment: @alexw Yes I did, but now I did it again and it worked. Thank you